# Can't access to func() in parent VC via Delegate/Protocol

Tags: swift, delegates, protocols, imessage-extension

Can't access to function in parent view controller from a child via delegate/protocol. `print()` doesn't print.

In Child VC I have this:

```
protocol MyViewControllerDelegate: class {
    func requestExpandedView()
}
    
class MyViewController: UIViewController {
        
    weak var delegate: MyViewControllerDelegate?
    ...

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

        print("\(indexPath) didSelectItemAt")
        
        delegate?.requestExpandedView()  
    }
}
```

In Parent VC I have this:

```
extension MessagesViewController: MyViewControllerDelegate {
    func requestExpandedView() {
        print("Done") // doesn't print anything
        requestPresentationStyle(.expanded)
    }
}
```

What's wrong?

Comment: What are you trying to do here. The flow is a bit unclear.

Comment: Did you set the `delegate` anywhere?

Comment: Hi! I want to access to func (print("Done") for example) in my parent view controller from a child view controller via protocol-delegate (delegate?.requestExpandedView())

Comment: I guess that `print("\(indexPath) didSelectItemAt")` is printed, what's the value of `delegate`, is it `nil`? If yes, why is it nil? Did you set it somewhere?

Comment: Is `MyViewController` embedded in `MessagesViewController` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set the `delegate` of `MyViewController` when creating its instance, i.e.

```
let vc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "MyViewController") as! MyViewController
vc.delegate = self
```

Comment: Yes! I missing this -> vc.delegate = self . Thank you!